# MySql Table schema performance issue

Tags: php, mysql, web, pdo, qsqlquery

I have the following table in mysql database:

```
CREATE TABLE `chronologicallists` (
`sno` int(250) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   
`empSno` int(11) NOT NULL,
`dateOfHearing` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `stageOfProceedings` text CHARACTER SET latin1,
 `isDecided` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
`caseSno` int(11) NOT NULL,
`isCurrent` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
`isOut` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
 `isTransferred` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
 `c_position` smallint(2) DEFAULT '1',
 `d_method` smallint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `reason_for_delay` text CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sno`)
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=274926 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

This table is working very fine for last 2+ years but since 3 days, it stuck by querying an DML execution. After executing 3 to 4 DML queries, it start taking too much time to execute the same query? 
It seems like there is any other process getting attach itself to mysqld and thus mysql execution get hang.

I am on windows 2012 Server -2 64-bit with mysql version 5.6.14. Total Size of this Table is : 30 MB

Please guide me what to do to improve my queries performance ?

Simple query example:

```
select COUNT(sno) as total from chronologicallists;
```

Comment: Example of query required.

Comment: What does `EXPLAIN select COUNT(sno) as total from chronologicallists;` show?

Comment: It says:                                                                 id=1 Select Type = SImple Table = Null Type=Null Possible_keys = Null Key=null key_len = null ref=null rows= null Extra = Select tables optimized away

Comment: there are apx 259000 records in this table

Answer (score 0):

Do a

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE chronologicallists
```

to update the index statistics and free unused disk-space.